# How to disable Search bar type hint

Tags: android, filter, android-edittext

I have some code for an editText search filter

```
EditText searchView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_view_edit);
searchView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
`list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);`          

searchView.setHint( getResources().getString( R.string.search_friend_hint ) );
searchView.addTextChangedListener( new TextWatcher() {

   @Override
  public void onTextChanged( CharSequence s, int start,int before, int count ) {

   Log.d("abc123", "onTextChanged " + s.toString() );
       if (TextUtils.isEmpty( s )) {
        list.clearTextFilter();
       } else {
    list.setFilterText( s.toString() );
       }
  }                     
  @Override
  public void beforeTextChanged( CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after ) {}

  @Override
  public void afterTextChanged( Editable s ) {}
});
```

but it will show type in hint by default:

[image]

How can i disable the hint?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not quite sure, what you're meaning. You explicitly set the hint in line 4: "searchView.setHint(...);". If you don't want the hint to be displayed, set it to ("").

Comment: No, It's not what i mean, i want to disable foreground "a"

Comment: this line use to set hint in editText when you do not type in anything 

searchView.setHint( getResources().getString( R.string.search_friend_hint ) );

Comment: The "a" with the black-transparent rectangle around it?

Answer (score 0):

The hint is not displayed by the `EditText`, but by the `ListView` with results. As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244710/android-prevent-text-field-pop-up-when-entering-text-in-a-searchview/10709353#10709353) suggests, to disable this tooltip/Toast, avoid `setTextFilterEnabled(true)` and `setFilterText`. Instead, use `getAdapter().getFilter().filter` directly:

```java
EditText searchView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_view_edit);
searchView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//DON'T list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

searchView.setHint( getResources().getString( R.string.search_friend_hint ) );
searchView.addTextChangedListener( new TextWatcher() {

   @Override
   public void onTextChanged( CharSequence s, int start,int before, int count ) {

       Log.d("abc123", "onTextChanged " + s.toString() );
       list.getAdapter().getFilter().filter(s);
   }                     
   @Override
   public void beforeTextChanged( CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after ) {}

   @Override
   public void afterTextChanged( Editable s ) {}
});
```

Also, for better UX, consider using `SearchView` and `onQueryTextChange` instead of `EditText` and `onTextChanged`,

Answer (score 0):

The 
hlidka's answer needs correction and class cast to Filterable:

```
TextWatcher tw = new TextWatcher(){

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            final LinearLayout sf=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.searchFilter);
            final LinearLayout sr=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.searchResultLayout);
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(s)) {
                mListView.clearTextFilter();
            } else {
                  ((Filterable)mListView.getAdapter()).getFilter().filter(s);
                //following line was causing the ugly popup window.
                //mListView.setFilterText(s.toString());
            }
            officeSearchAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    };
```